# OLS Estimator Summation Proof

Tags: regression

In deriving the OLS estimators for 1 variable, I am trying to convert

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N X_iY_i- N\bar{X}\bar{Y} }{\sum_{i=1}^NX^2_i - N(\bar{X})^2}
\end{align}
$$

to the final form

$$
\hat{\beta_1} = 
\frac{\sum^N_{i=1}\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_i-\bar{X}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
Y_i-\bar{Y}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}}
{\sum^N_{i=1}\begin{pmatrix}X_i - \bar{X}\end{pmatrix}^2}
$$

In particular, I'm trying to show the following 2 sums are valid:
$\sum_{i=1}^N\begin{bmatrix}(X_i -\bar{X})(Y_i -\bar{Y})\end{bmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^N X_iY_i- N\bar{X}\bar{Y} $

and
$\sum_{i=1}^N(X_i -\bar{X})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^NX^2_i - N(\bar{X})^2 $

What's the best way to show the following sums?

Comment: I think the question is valid and relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N[(X_i -\bar{X})(Y_i -\bar{Y})]&=\sum_{i=1}^N[X_i Y_i-\bar{X}Y_i-X_i\bar{Y}+\bar{X}\bar{Y}]
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i Y_i- \sum_{i=1}^N\bar{X}Y_i- \sum_{i=1}^NX_ i\bar{Y}+\sum_{i=1}^N\bar{X}\bar{Y}
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i Y_i- \bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^NY_i- \bar{Y}\sum_{i=1}^NX_ i+\bar{X}\bar{Y}\sum_{i=1}^N 1
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i Y_i- \bar{X} (N \bar{Y})- \bar{Y}(N \bar{X})+N\bar{X}\bar{Y}
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^N X_iY_i- N\bar{X}\bar{Y}
\end{align}

The other one follows similarly.